# unknown type name 'uint32_t', MinGW

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I get the error `unknown type name 'uint32_t'` and included `stdint.h`. `uint8_t` doesn't produce an error, neither does `uint16_t`.

I'm using MinGW and the following make-lines:

```
# Build for Windows under MinGW
#MINGWDBG= -DDEBUG -O0
MINGWDBG= -DNDEBUG -Os
#MINGWOPT= -W -Wall -mthreads -Wl,--subsystem,console $(MINGWDBG) -DHAVE_STDINT
MINGWOPT= -W -Wall -mthreads -Wl,--subsystem,windows $(MINGWDBG)
mingw:
    windres win32\res.rc win32\res.o
    gcc $(MINGWOPT) mongoose.c -lws2_32 \
        -shared -Wl,--out-implib=$(PROG).lib -o $(PROG).dll
    gcc $(MINGWOPT) mongoose.c main.c win32\res.o -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 \
        -o $(PROG).exe
```

Code:

```
uint32_t function(void) {
    return VALUE;
}
```

And the includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mongoose.h"
#include "main.h"
#include <stdint.h>
```

Comment: Providing uint32_t is optional. update your box, you are using a 16bit processor.

Comment: Updated info. Nice comment Johannes Schaub :) but really not using a 16 bit processor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer my own question, changing the order of the includes seemed to do the trick.

Comment: standard headers can be used in any order, you messed something in your own headers. If `uint32_t` is mentioned in any of your own headers, stdint.h also has to be included in these headers.

Comment: Yes, that would probably be it. The includesnippet is from main.c and main.h has a uin32_t var. So changing the order fixed this.

Comment: In this case, you should consider to include stdint in this header!

Answer (score 12):

If

```
#include "main.h"
#include <stdint.h>
```

didn't work, but

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "main.h"
```

did, it is likely that your `main.h` file relies on `stdint.h`. That means you should add `#include <stdint.h>` to `main.h`.